# Assigning read line to a variable without >>

Tags: c++

Just getting started with C++, done a bit of C but one thing I don't get is that you can't substitute `>>` for `=`?

My code below:

```
char output[100];
if (myReadFile.is_open())
{
    for(int i=0; i != random_integer; i++)
    {
       if(i == random_integer-1){
        myReadFile >> output;
        printf("%s",output);
       }
    }
}
myReadFile.close();
```

I'd like to change `myReadFile >> output` to `output = myReadFile` but you can't do that?

My second question is, I want to measure the length of the string that I assign to output, how can I do that without looping through the whole char array?

TIA

Comment: No, you can't assign a file to an array of `char`. What kind of behavior were you expecting?

Comment: Why do you think that you ought to be able to use `=` instead of `>>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you can't use `=` instead of `>>` is because they're two unrelated operators.

To solve the string-length issue, don't use a raw `char` array.  Use a `std::string` instead, because it manages its own memory internally:

```
std::string str;

myReadFile >> str;
```

Comment: And is it easy to then get its size?

Comment: @Eric: Yes, just use `str.size()`.

Answer (score -2):

You can't use the `=` operator, but there's no reason why you should hesitate to pick another one. I think `+` makes sense for your situation:

```
char* operator+ (char* s, std::istream &in) {
    in >> s;
    return s;
}
```

To use this with your code, try this:

```
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

char* operator+ (char* s, std::istream &in) {
    in >> s;
    return s;
}


int main(){
    std::fstream myReadFile ("test.txt", std::fstream::in);
    int random_integer = 4;

    /*start your code*/
    char output[100];
    if (myReadFile.is_open())
    {
        for(int i=0; i != random_integer; i++)
        {
           if(i == random_integer-1){
            output + myReadFile;
            printf("%s",output);
           }
        }
    }
    /*end your code*/
}
```

test.txt contents:

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
dddd
eeee
```

output from code:

```
aaaa
```

---

**Jokes aside**, you should *not* actually attempt to use a different operator for this situation. Your code is reading from an input (file) stream, so you should use the operator `>>` which makes that clear.

C++ has a feature called 'operator overloading' which I demonstrated above which allows you to modify the behavior of the built-in operators for types of your choice. However you must be careful to not abuse the feature in such a way that makes the operation more difficult to understand.

In general when making a design choice like this in programming, always go for the option that makes your code easier to understand for the reader. This applies to variable names, commenting, etc..

Comment: I'm not sure this is a very helpful answer at the moment.